# where are iOS layout guidelines?

Tags: ios

I have been trying to find a reference with details on the offset guidelines for subview layouts in iOS with no luck.  I first looked in the IB guide, and in the section about layouts, it indicates that the IB guides (the blue lines) use guidelines supposedly described in detail in the iOS Mobile HIG, but I searched that document and didn't find any such guidelines.

Anyone know where it's specified, or am I just going to have to piddle with IB and write down numbers on sticky notes?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any documentation specific to what you are asking (except for the standard element dimensions described in the docs). [TapWorthy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449381650) is worth a read and it will definitely be of help if you want to understand the rationale behind some of Apple's (and others') UI design decisions.

Answer (score 1):

This document seems better suited to layout, they refer to it as views: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the [iOS UI Element Usage Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW1) (fixed my broken link..)

Comment: your link is broken.  and....that section of the HIG doesn't contain the info I'm looking for.

Comment: apologies on the broken link.  @Ben, I misunderstood your question - you are looking for like specific pixel/percent values?

Comment: Yes - I'm going some manual layouts without IB and wanted to use the same guidelines, but have been unable to find them documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old but since It shows as the first answer in DDG I'll post the link in [iOS Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH66-SW1).